# issue to pass w3c validator

Tags: php, mysql, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [w3 validation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809884/w3-validation-issue)

i can't pass the w3c validator for my site ( http://www.bbway.com )

i got 4 error's

1- Line 294, Column 19: end tag for "tr" which is not finished

```
</td></tr><tr></tr></table>
```

2- Line 362, Column 19: end tag for "tr" which is not finished

```
</td></tr><tr></tr></table>
```

3- Line 400, Column 19: end tag for "tr" which is not finished

```
</td></tr><tr></tr></table>
```

4- Line 438, Column 19: end tag for "tr" which is not finished

```
</td></tr><tr></tr></table>
```

all the top errors comes from my (multi columns code) i use this code

```
$getnewbrds=$db->query("select id,userid,title,added_date,active
from brd
where active='1' order by id desc limit 9");
echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5"><tr>';
$count = 0;
$max = 3;
while($fetch_newbrds=$db->fetch($getnewbrds)){
$count++;

$getbrduser  = get_val("id,name","users","where id='$fetch_newbrds[userid]'","name");
$getbrduseri = get_val("id,name","users","where id='$fetch_newbrds[userid]'","id");


echo '<td align="center" width="30%" valign="top">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td height="50" colspan="2" align="center">
<a href="showbrd-'.$fetch_newbrds['id'].'.html" title="'.$fetch_newbrds['title'].'">
'.$fetch_newbrds['title'].'</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right" class="brduseronmain">
<a href="users-'.$getbrduseri.'.html" title="'.$getbrduser.'">'.$getbrduser.'
<span>'.$fetch_newbrds['added_date'].'</span>
</a>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</td>';    


if($count >= $max){
   $count = 0;
   echo '</tr><tr>';
 } 

}

echo '</tr></table>';
```

could you please share your fixes for this issue.

Comment: I'd take it an empty `<tr>` is not allowed, but the added complexity in your PHP is not worth having completely valid HTML, I'd say.

Comment: @Rocket, neither are answered :)

Comment: Your code creates wayyy too many nested tables.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: And both are for the same URL.

Comment: As [it was already told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809884/w3-validation-issue#comment12496522_9809884), and what the validator is trying to say, you can't have an empty tr tag.

Comment: Muhahaha. Well I answered it nonetheless.

Comment: This is just one of the morons who reposts a question because it didn't get answered the first time and thinks no one will notice because of a different username.

Comment: i asked for sharring your idea's to fix this issue so please if you dont have any thing to say (please be away from this Question ).

Comment: If you read your first question's comments, you shouldn't have reposted your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
if($count >= $max){
   $count = 0;
   echo '</tr><tr>';
}
```

You need to add logic so that on the last iteration it doesn't output an empty row.

You could do this with another counter or better yet don't pre-wrap the `<tr>` outside the while.

Comment: i tried to do many ways to split them but always i can't pass the validator

Comment: If he did it with floating DIV blocks (or [something else](http://www.woothemes.com/2011/05/responsive-design-using-css3-media-queries/)) he wouldn't have to worry about tables at all.

Comment: @AndrewR, agreed. But that's beyond the scope of the question. Remove the empty `<tr>` is a simple matter of moving around a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, fixed, I think, didn't test it since you didn't provide data I could test with it, find more info below.

```
$getnewbrds=$db->query("
    select 
        id,
        userid,
        title,
        added_date,
        active
    from 
        brd
    where 
        active='1' 
    order by 
        id desc 
    limit 9
");

$count  = 0;
$max    = 3;

$html = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">';

while($fetch_newbrds = $db->fetch($getnewbrds)) {
    $count++;

    if($count % $max === 1){
        $html .= '<tr>';
    }

    $getbrduser  = get_val("id,name","users","where id='$fetch_newbrds[userid]'","name");
    $getbrduseri = get_val("id,name","users","where id='$fetch_newbrds[userid]'","id");

    $html .= '
    <td align="center" width="30%" valign="top">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td height="50" colspan="2" align="center">
                    <a href="showbrd-'.$fetch_newbrds['id'].'.html" title="'.$fetch_newbrds['title'].'">
                        '.$fetch_newbrds['title'].'
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right" class="brduseronmain">
                    <a href="users-'.$getbrduseri.'.html" title="'.$getbrduser.'">'.$getbrduser.'
                        <span>'.$fetch_newbrds['added_date'].'</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    ';

    if($count % $max === 0){
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
}

if($count % $max !== 0) {
        while($count % $max !== 0) {
            $html .= '<td></td>';
            $count++;
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
```

Few things I did

1. Indented your code properly; do that yourself before even trying to
   post a question
2. Captured the html in a variable first echo'ed when
   done; right to the output is not the best way...

I used modulus to figure out if `$count` divided by `$max` leaves `1` to determine if I should open a new `<tr>`... and did the same check to see if the remainder would be 0 to see if I need to close it... Then at last after the while I check if the 
 was closed or not, if not add `<td></td>` until it is to keep the html valid and eventually close the last `<tr>`.